# Google Spreadsheet, finding the previous weekday

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-docs

In Google Spreadsheet, or excel if its the same, how do I find the last weekday of day D only if D is not a weekday itself.

I.E:

```
If D equals weekday = do nothing (D equals D).
If D equals weekend = D equals last weekday.
```

Edit: i tried this to get the workday one month away:

```
WORKDAY(EDATE(N18, 1)+1, -1)
```

But I Was getting some weird results. Perhaps it counts red days as well, but I never specified the region anywhere.

Edit again:

This above example actually works, eg:

```
=WORKDAY("2013-04-06"+1, -1)
```

Comment: You have been with SO for more than `4` years now :) You should know better than to ask a question and expect someone to do the job for you. Sorry but I will have to vote this question to be closed. Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: @Siddarth Rout : lol. fair enough. I added what I tried. and some thoughts as well :)

Comment: I am happy that you took the feedback in a positive manner :) I have retracted my vote and yes... + 1 ;)

Comment: This formula looks good to me `=WORKDAY(EDATE(N18, 1)+1, -1)` - can you give an example where you don't get the result you want....and what the required result should be in that case

Comment: Actually it does work. I must have mixed up the days somehow. I was almost certain it didnt work, oh well =)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
=WORKDAY("2013-04-06"+1, -1)
```

...does the trick.

Answer (score 4):

Another option may be:

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(D1, 2) > 5, D1 - (WEEKDAY(D1, 2) - 5), D1)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not so straightforward, but you can use something like that:

```
=IF(OR(WEEKDAY(A1)=1,WEEKDAY(A1)=7),A1-CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(A1),2,,,,,,1),A1)
```

Basically, if the weekday is 1 or 7 (Sunday or Saturday, as this is how Excel treats weekdays), return the date minus 2 if Sunday or minus 1 if Saturday, else the date itself.