# Query Google finance for previous currency data (weekdays only) within google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

After reviewing the following:

[On Google Spreadsheet how can you query 'GoogleFinance' for a past exchange rate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20607627/on-google-spreadsheet-how-can-you-query-googlefinance-for-a-past-exchange-rate)

and subsequently:

[Google Spreadsheet, finding the previous weekday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19345406/google-spreadsheet-finding-the-previous-weekday)

I tried the following:

`=(GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:USDGBP", "price", WORKDAY("1/1/2020"+1,-1), WORKDAY("1/8/2020"+1,-1)))`

However this is return weekend values also (not required)

```
Date                Close
1/1/2020 23:58:00   0.7548
1/2/2020 23:58:00   0.7606
1/3/2020 23:58:00   0.7644967
1/4/2020 23:58:00   0.7640879
1/5/2020 23:58:00   0.764575
1/6/2020 23:58:00   0.75925
1/7/2020 23:58:00   0.7625
1/8/2020 23:58:00   0.7631
```

I just wish to query the past prices for weekdays only:

Expected:

```
Date                Close
1/1/2020 23:58:00   0.7548
1/2/2020 23:58:00   0.7606
1/3/2020 23:58:00   0.7644967
1/6/2020 23:58:00   0.75925
1/7/2020 23:58:00   0.7625
1/8/2020 23:58:00   0.7631
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Date","Close";QUERY(N(GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:USDGBP", "price", WORKDAY("1/1/2020"+1,-1), WORKDAY("1/8/2020"+1,-1))),"where (Col1 % 7)>2")})
```